# Select query usingTaffyDB not working

Tags: javascript, database, taffydb

I'm just starting to play around with TaffyDB and it's acting funny...and I don't know if that's because I'm doing something wrong or what.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="taffydb-master/taffy.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 

  <script>

    var people = TAFFY([{name:"George", address:"FooBar st."},
       {name:"Carl", address: "Foo st."},
       {name: "Kyle", address:"Baz st."}]);

    document.write(people().first());
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

This returns and I don't know why. I want it to return the whole thing.

```
[object Object]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: people().first() returns an object. try `document.write(people().first().toString());`

Comment: @A.J I did try that and it returned the same thing. I really don't know what's going on.